# Put android tabs in center of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I tried Android action bar with tabs. As you see in this picture:

[image: This]
<sub>(source: [persiangig.com](http://amirarcane.persiangig.com/PlqTd.png))</sub>

My action bar looks good in phones but in tablets it is not right, the tabs stick left. This picture shows what I mean, how can I put the tabs to center in tablets too?

[image: This]
<sub>(source: [persiangig.com](http://amirarcane.persiangig.com/Untitled-1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The tabs are aligned left because, in Android, the action bar is used for both navigation and Activity- or Fragment-specific actions. You don't have any in this screenshot, but menu actions that are added to the action bar will be aligned to the right.

If you must have your tabs centered for some reason, you'll have to write your own action bar. I would recommend against this, since it's a lot of work to intentionally go against user expectations. Instead, use Android's built-in action bar layout and design your app to accommodate it.